# Patttern matching within collection

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I would like to look for a specific pattern inside a Seq. I tried to use at the same time :+ and +: operators but it doesn't seem to work even though it compiles, for now I have to rely on 'dropwhile' operation first and then pattern match on the beginning of the collection.

Is it not possible to write something like that in Scala ? 'from' and 'to' are existing variables

```
case beginColl :+ `from` +: someElement +: `to` +: tail => true
```

Edit : it is a Seq of objects , not a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never work in that definition as you can not wildcard any subsequence except tail in result of `unapplySeq`. 
But let me suggest a workaround.

Lets define this helper:

```
object Span {
  class Spanner[T](pred: T => Boolean) {
    def unapply(seq: Seq[T]) = for {
      idx <- Some(seq.indexWhere(pred)) if idx >= 0
      (start, elem +: end) = seq.splitAt(idx)
    } yield (start, end)
  }
  def apply[T](pred: T => Boolean) = new Spanner(pred)
}
```

This allows us to define more interesting matchers like this function:

```
def splitter[T](from:T, to:T): PartialFunction[Seq[T], Seq[Seq[T]]] = {
  val From = Span[T](_ == from)
  val To = Span[T](_ == to)

  {
    case From(prefix, To(middle, postfix)) => Seq(prefix, middle, postfix)
  }
}
```

So if we specialize it to:

```
val mySplitter = splitter("from", "to").lift
```

We could get appropriate results:

```
mySplitter(Seq("1", "2", "to", "3", "4", "from", "5", "6")) // None
mySplitter(Seq("1", "2", "from", "3", "4", "to", "5", "6")) // Some(List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5, 6)))
```

Lets try to clarify how compiler understands your syntax, lets define

```
def splitter2(from: AnyRef, to: AnyRef): PartialFunction[Seq[_], AnyRef] = {
  case beginColl :+ `from` +: someElement +: `to` +: tail => (beginColl, someElement, tail)
}
val mySplitter2 = splitter2("from", "to").lift
```

So if we try to match

```
mySplitter2(Seq("1", "2", "from", "3", "4 ", "to", "5", "6"))
```

We'll surely get `None`

But if we try

```
mySplitter2(Seq("1", "2", Seq("from", "3", "to", "4", "5")))
```

Suddenly we getting `Some(...)`

So compiler just understood your expression as _match element as

```
beginColl :+ __last
```

then match `__last` as

```
`from` +: someElement +: `to` +: tail
```

Which is basically *verify this is non-empty `Seq` last element of which is 
another `Seq` that consists of at least three elements, first and third of these are `from` and `to`*

Comment: Ok, so the short answer to my question is 'not possible' .... I am quite disappointed honestly but at least it is clear.

Comment: @sam Yes. My point is: this is not possible **syntactically**, but lot's of things are possible **semantically** by using custom matchers.

Comment: I am simply surprised that it compiles then. Is it failing at runtime but hidden by the pattern matching process ?

Comment: @sam Why this is compiles - is another question. I'll try to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that you may need to recognize a sequence like this:

```
val test = Seq("x", "from", "y", "to", "z")

test match {
  case _ :: "from" :: _ :: "to" :: _ => true
  case _ => false
}
```

But as you need to know if the sequence has a particular characteristic, I would try this:

```
test match {
  case list if (list.indexOf("from") < list.indexOf("to")) => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Comment: it is in fact a Seq of objects, sorry for not saying it, I edited my post

Comment: Even as a `Seq[Object]` works.
Perhaps you could add an example of the sequence.

Comment: I don't see how it could work since :: is only usable on List

Comment: If you check :: in this [link](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon) you can see all the types that can use :: with.

Comment: In this link you clearly see that this operator extends List so it is only for Lists , but in your case it is working because the default implementation of a Seq is a List , so indeed you have a List with this code. But mine could be any type of Seq

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. But `::` is more than a `List` operator. I have found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807540/scala-pattern-matching-on-sequences-other-than-lists) post about it.

Comment: True, it is more than that I didn't know :) . But it seems it will  not fit my requirements, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
case Seq(_, `from`, _, `to`, _*) => true
```

EDIT:

if there are more elements before 'from', dropWhile is a good solution, an alternative (but less efficient) way could be :

```
def matchSeq[T](s: Seq[T]): Boolean = s match { 
    case Seq(_, `from`, _, `to`, _*) => true
    case Seq(a, b@_*) => matchSeq(b) 
    case _ => false 
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, probably because there could be any number of elements before `from`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `containsSlice` to check the sequence contains subsequence, or you can compare indexes of elements you are looking for. i.e:

```
val test = Seq("x", "from", "y", "to", "z")
val test2 = Seq("u", "w", "x", "from", "y", "to", "z")

test match {
  case s if s.indexOf("to") - s.indexOf("from") == 2 => true
  case _ => false
} //true in both cases.
```

Comment: if index of "to" is 1 and "from" does not exist, it gives a false positive.