# Can we have an array of by-name-parameter functions?

Tags: scala

In Scala we have a by-name-parameters where we can write

```
def foo[T](f: => T):T = {
   f // invokes f    
}
// use as:
foo(println("hello"))
```

I now want to do the same with an array of methods, that is I want to use them as:

```
def foo[T](f:Array[ => T]):T = {     // does not work
   f(0) // invokes f(0)              // does not work
}
foo(println("hi"), println("hello")) // does not work
```

Is there any way to do what I want? The best I have come up with is:

```
def foo[T](f:() => T *):T = {
   f(0)() // invokes f(0)    
}
// use as:
foo(() => println("hi"), () => println("hello"))
```

or

```
def foo[T](f:Array[() => T]):T = { 
   f(0)() // invokes f(0)    
}
// use as: 
foo(Array(() => println("hi"), () => println("hello")))
```

EDIT: The proposed SIP-24 is not very useful as pointed out by Seth Tisue in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32917455/243233).

An example where this will be problematic is the following code of a utility function `trycatch`:

```
type unitToT[T] = ()=>T
def trycatch[T](list:unitToT[T] *):T = list.size match {
  case i if i > 1 => 
    try list.head()
    catch { case t:Any => trycatch(list.tail: _*) }
  case 1 => list(0)()
  case _ => throw new Exception("call list must be non-empty")
}
```

Here `trycatch` takes a list of methods of type `()=>T` and applies each element successively until it succeeds or the end is reached.

Now suppose I have two methods:

```
def getYahooRate(currencyA:String, currencyB:String):Double = ???
```

and

```
def getGoogleRate(currencyA:String, currencyB:String):Double = ???
```

that convert one unit of `currencyA` to `currencyB` and output `Double`.

I use `trycatch` as:

```
val usdEuroRate = trycatch(() => getYahooRate("USD", "EUR"), 
                           () => getGoogleRate("USD", "EUR"))
```

I would have preferred:

```
val usdEuroRate = trycatch(getYahooRate("USD", "EUR"), 
                           getGoogleRate("USD", "EUR")) // does not work
```

In the example above, I would like `getGoogleRate("USD", "EUR")` to be invoked only if `getYahooRate("USD", "EUR")` throws an exception. This is not the intended behavior of SIP-24.

Comment: I think there's a way to do this using, implicits, let me see...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Scala 2.11.7, the answer is no.  However, there is [SIP-24](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/repeated-byname.html), so in some future version your `f: => T*` version may be possible.

Comment: But SIP-24 doesn't allow you to pick and choose which items get evaluated: "all arguments are evaluated each time the parameter is referenced in the called method". So `f(0)` won't just print "hi". It will print both "hi" and "hello".

Comment: @SethTisue Interesting observation. That that makes such features not very useful.

Comment: @SethTisue Updated my question with an example where the behavior of SIP-24 would be undesirable. I cannot think of one example where that intended behavior will actually be *desirable*. Anyone care to enlighten me?

Comment: I can't, but I've added a link to this Q&A from the SIP.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://scastie.org/23981) is a solution, although with a few restrictions compared to direct call-by-name:

```
import scala.util.control.NonFatal


object Main extends App {
  implicit class Attempt[+A](f: => A) {
    def apply(): A = f
  }

  def tryCatch[T](attempts: Attempt[T]*): T = attempts.toList match {
    case a :: b :: rest =>
      try a()
      catch {
        case NonFatal(e) =>
          tryCatch(b :: rest: _*)
      }
    case a :: Nil =>
      a()
    case Nil => throw new Exception("call list must be non-empty")
  }

  def a = println("Hi")
  def b: Unit = sys.error("one")
  def c = println("bye")
  tryCatch(a, b, c)

  def d: Int = sys.error("two")
  def e = { println("here"); 45 }
  def f = println("not here")

  val result = tryCatch(d, e, f)

  println("Result is " + result)
}
```

The restrictions are:

1. Using a block as an argument won't work; only the last expression of the block will be wrapped in an `Attempt`.
2. If the expression is of type `Nothing` (e.g., if `b` and `d` weren't annotated), the conversion to `Attempt` is not inserted since `Nothing` is a subtype of every type, including `Attempt`. Presumably the same would apply for an expression of type `Null`.

Comment: Note: I refactored tryCatch a bit (1) instead of using .size or indexes, which are more error-prone and less idiomatic in scala, I use a standard List recursion; (2) I use the NonFatal extractor so e.g. OOM won't be swallowed (see NonFatal docs); (3) capitalized the C