# Why can't I match on a Stream?

Tags: scala

Specifically:

```
scala> def f(n: Seq[Any]) = n match { 
     case Nil => "Empty" 
     case h :: t => "Non-empty" 
}
f: (n: Seq[Any])String

scala> f(Stream())
res1: String = Empty

scala> f(List(1))
res17: String = Non-empty

scala> f(Stream(1))
scala.MatchError: Stream(1, ?) (of class scala.collection.immutable.Stream$Cons)
  at .f(<console>:13)
  ... 33 elided
```

There are a lot of other ways to implement this, but at written the code was statically safe and failed at run time.  What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `Stream`, the **concat** symbol should be `#::`, the **pattern match** should like:

```
  def f(n: Seq[Any]) = n match {
    case Nil => "Empty"
    case h :: t => "Non-empty"
    case h #:: t => "Non-empty stream"
  }
```

for `::` is for `List` / `Seq`  type(`List` extends from `Seq`:) ), see:

```
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
```

Comment: `List` extends from `Seq`.

Comment: @Nyavro `Seq(1, 2)` is a `List`. That is, `List` is the default `Seq`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `::` to deconstruct a `List` and not a `Stream`. Since the `Stream` you provide does not match a `List`, you get a `MatchError`. If you want `f` to support streams using that type of matching (extractors), you can use `#::`.

```
def f(n: Seq[Any]) = n match {
  case Nil => "Empty"
  case h :: t => "Non-empty"
  case h #:: t => "Non-empty"
}
```

In general, this approach is very fragile because both extractor types shown above will only work for those two types of `Seq`. Others maybe break. If all you care about is determining whether or not the `Seq` is empty or not, then simply use `n.nonEmpty` or `n.isEmpty` and deal with the `Boolean` result. Otherwise, trying to provide an exhaustive match on a trait that is not sealed is bound to fail.

You can also use the `Seq` extractor:

```
def f(n: Seq[Any]) = n match { 
  case Nil => "Empty" 
  case Seq(_*) => "Non-empty" 
}
```

Comment: Really, is `#::` a thing? How am I even suppose to google that.

Comment: No more difficult than googling `::`.

Comment: `Stream` has its own cons, it shouldn't be so surprising: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html

Comment: You can even match for head and tail with the Seq syntax: `Seq(h, t @ _*)`.

Answer (score 0):

While other answers show correctly an extractor specific for `Stream`, which is `#::`, there exists an extractor for `Seq` (and anything derived from `SeqLike`) - it is `+:`, this works for both `List` (as `::`) and `Stream` (as `#::). With this extractor you can easily write a function which works with both:

```
def f(n: Seq[Any]) = n match { 
  case h +: t => "Non-empty" 
  case _ => "Empty" 
}
```

See also [Scala pattern matching on sequences other than Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19147469/16673)