# Scala pattern match not working on Stream?

Tags: scala

I do a group-by and I get `key -> Stream(of values)`

I then need to do a pattern match on the stream collection to access the last item
but the pattern match doesn't work.

When I manually build the list of values using Seq the same pattern match code works

So my question is there a way to convert the Stream to Seq or List?

The IDE says `toSeq` is redundant

Comment: How are you doing the pattern match?, Which Stream are you talking about, the scala one, the java one, the akka one?, Can you please share a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). - BTW, if you are trying to pattern match the stream itself using `Nil` & `x :: xs` that won't work, first, those are specific to `List`, second usually streams are not ADTs, thus they are not pattern matcheable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I manually build the list of values using Seq the same pattern match code works

In scala 2.12, `Seq` (or sequence) are defaulted to `List`, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56147577/what-happens-when-you-create-a-seq-object-with-seq1-2-3):

```scala
scala> Seq(1,2,3)
res3: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

This is probably why the pattern matching works on your sequence (which happens to be a `List`) but not an a `Stream`, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545448/why-cant-i-match-on-a-stream).

> The IDE says toSeq is redundant

`Stream` are indeed `Seq`:

```scala
Stream(1,2,3).toSeq
res4: collection.immutable.Seq[Int] = Stream(1, 2, 3)
```

> So my question is there a way to convert the Stream to Seq or List?

To transform a `Stream` into a `List`, you can call the `.toList` method:

```scala
Stream(1,2,3).toList
res5: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: What collection is mostly used in scala List or Seq?

Comment: `List` are a specific type of a `Seq` btw, (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866639/difference-between-a-seq-and-a-list-in-scala))... So which type of `Seq` to use, really depends on your use case... `List` are quite common, and are standard, if you need an access to the head in a contant time...

Answer (score 2):

Or with this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42545638/2750966) you don't have to transform to `List`:

```
val n: Seq[Any] = Stream(..)
n match {
    case Nil => "Empty"
    case h :: t => "Non-empty"
    case h #:: t => "Non-empty stream"
  }
```

> For Stream, the concat symbol should be #::, the pattern match should like:

Make sure you reverse the Stream - so you get the last element, here an example:

```
n.reverse match {
    case Nil => "Empty"
    case h #:: _ => s"last element is $h"
  }
```

Check it here [ScalaFiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/AtnOEJJ/0)

Comment: `Nil` does not work for streams, you should use `Stream.Empty`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530794/why-cant-i-pattern-match-on-stream-empty-in-scala). - BTW, reversing a _possibly_ **infinite** collection does not seems like a good idea to.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: we pattern match to a `Seq` not `Stream` (check https://scalafiddle.io/sf/UdJCMhM/1). jakstack requirement is to match the last element - so I assumed the `Stream` is not infinite - otherwise you are right of course ;) .